# VBA Macro for Hyperion is slow

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have Hyperion Macro Refresh code as below:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function HypMenuVRefresh Lib "HsAddin" () As Long

i = 1
Count = wb9.Worksheets.Count

Do While i <= Count
wb9.Activate

Sheets(i).Select

Call HypMenuVRefresh
```

it is taking too much time to complete the task

i got to know the reason refreshing file is have linked excel sheet

is there any alternative to referesh hyperion excel sheet faster even files having links in it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.